# ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

May be this is repeated question, but the solutions provided on net including the stackoverflow Q-A not resolved my issue. CKEditor (4.5.3) integrated in MVC application. CKEditor is using on textarea in partial view. Same partial view used in create and Edit post form. both form having same .chtml page. 
Partial view :

```
  <textarea id="Description" name="Description" class="form-control" >@Html.Raw(Model.Description)</textarea>
```

Having script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    CKEDITOR.replace('Description', {
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '@Url.Action("UploadEditorImage", "Administrator")',
        htmlEncodeOutput: true
    });
</script>
```

In .CHTML page added :  `<script src="~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>` which is generating proper js as examined in response.

config.js :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {     
    config.image_previewText = CKEDITOR.tools.repeat(' ', 2);
    config.extraPlugins = 'onchange';   
};
```

In Create able to see upload image control but in edit, its not even showing control. in Browser error console showing

```
ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined
```

Why should this. Edit form having

```
 $("#Description").val(CKEDITOR.instances['Description'].getData());
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: try to assign CKEDITOR_BASEPATH variable before loading the ckeditor.js and check if it is works or not?

Comment: Are there any other JS errors besides that one?